# Login Page not redirecting on session active

Tags: php

I've done a login page in a site for some company and every seemed to be alright until I notice a minor issue, important anyway. The session starts an everything works ok, except that I can't redirect from the login page if the session is already started. I mean if I type the address:

> mydomain/myfolder/login.php

It stays there and can't redirect to the main page, because it looks like the session data is not available to this page. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php

$usuarios = simplexml_load_file('__usuarios__mensajes.xml');
$goLogin = false;
$nameOK = false;
$passOK = false;
$messagesPage = "index.php";

if($_SESSION["loggedIn"])$passOK = true;

if((isset($_POST["MM_insert"]) && $_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")){
    $nombre =  $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    foreach($usuarios->usuario as $usuario){
        $attr = $usuario->attributes();

        if($nombre == $attr["nombre"]){
            $nameOK = true;
            if($password == $attr["password"]){

                $goLogin = true;
                $passOK = true;
                $displayName = (string)$attr["displayName"];

                }               
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if($passOK){
                session_start();

                $_SESSION["usuario"]= $_POST["user"];
                $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
                $_SESSION["userDisplayName"]= $displayName;                 

                header(sprintf("Location: %s", $messagesPage));

            }
?>
```

Comment: where's your `session_start()` by the way?

Comment: put session_start() all the way at the top instead of in if($passOK){}

Comment: also if you just go to that page login.php you won't have your $_POST data anymore so $displayName etc won't be set and other variables

Comment: Ok... I've got the answer. Thank you very much for your feedback. The issue was only the session thing, the $_POST data was already considered. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Before you use `$_SESSION`, use `session_start()` first. So it should be like this:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION["loggedIn"])$passOK = true;
```